RSpec Chrome Webdriver tests fails on RSpec::Core::MultipleExceptionError: no such window - invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string
So without any good  reason my Rails 7.2 RSpec system test that run on headless Chrome Selenium Webdriver started to fail on  error
RSpec::Core::MultipleExceptionError: no such window
  (Session info: chrome=127.0.6533.88)

invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=127.0.6533.88)

Full error:

No code change no config change
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_headless do |app|
  options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

  options.add_argument("--headless=new") unless ENV["GUI"] == "on"
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
  options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
  options.add_argument("--window-size=1400,1400")


  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end


Turns out this was due to an update of my Chrome on my OSx. The main change was that this update contained "Select Your Search Engine" prompt:

and that will cause webdriver to switch context to different screen
solution is to turn off this prompt with
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_headless do |app|
  options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  # ...
  options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")

works !
